# mysql select 6th thru 10th (natural order) records

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table:

```
ID    |     Name
0183        namez
2543        etc
2654        etc
4364        namez
3246        namey
3745        namew
3464        namem
7524        etc
2459
2457
0845
9325
```

I need to be able to select the 6th thru 10th rows or the 4th thru 25th or whatever, so that I can select only the rows that I need without using any kind of Id column, also it's alway Xth "thru" Yth, because I'm not hardcoding an column names here, I can't use order by but have to use natural order. Is this even possible? Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: What the heck is "natural order"?

Comment: I guess he refers to not using an ORDER BY clause in the query, but using the default ordering.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "natural order". Rows in a relation table **are not sorted**. The DBMS is free to return the rows in *any* order it seems fit if you don't specfiy an order by.

Answer (score 4):

you need to pass a `LIMIT` clause to your `SELECT` query. In MySQL this would be:

```
SELECT * FROM simpletable LIMIT 5, 5;
```

NOTE:

- the first number is the **offset**, it needs to be the first row minus one, (i.e. 6 - 1).
- the second is the number of rows returned, this needs to be **last row - offset** (i.e. 10 - 5).

SEE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Comment: Limit without an order by is not very useful.

Comment: If the person asking explicitly mentions that (s)he can not use `ORDER BY` and there are 3 comments below the question discussing exactly this fact, a comment like yours is not very usefull either.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tables ORDER BY ID LIMIT 4, 10
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tables
ORDER BY ID
LIMIT 5, 5
```

Comment: TRENT gave this answer first

Comment: what i'm doing is selecting a range of rows, by the number they are listed in the database. also this is for any table the table names, column names and values and types are all completely unknown

Comment: can you use limit without orderby? also does limit 4, 10  get rows 4-10

Comment: Your terminology & problem description don't quite make sense.

Comment: Yes, you can absolutely use limit without order by. I would definitely recommend simply trying a quick query to determine the answer to that type of question.

Comment: note that the values for your `LIMIT` clause return elemts 5 through 14, not 5 through 10

Comment: @flexy, very true. My bad. Fixed my answer.

Comment: okay 1. i'll give a better description and 2. work on the query in the background, heres the problem, I have a table with two columns and 5 rows, now the column names could be anything, so no names cannot be hard coded, like with ORDER BY ID, and I want the 2nd, 3rd and 4th records from the table

Comment: Your situation sounds fairly unconventional to not have a grip on what your schema (column names) will be in advance. It's a best-practice to have an ID column set to AUTO INCREMENT that will generate an artificial ID for every tuple(record) in a database. I would recommend you consider including an AUTO INCREMENT ID column in every table of your database. Just an added thought, your description sounds a bit like you're dealing with unstructured data -- maybe a NoSQL database like MongoDB would be useful for you.

Comment: so far $var = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM APP_SUPERTEMP LIMIT 5, 10');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($var)) {
 $myvar[] = $row;
}
var_dump($myvar);

Comment: i really like the auto increment ID, but the purpose of the script is to be able to plug the script into any table and display a form of the contents using nothing but the tablename, if were using only my databases and tables then your idea is what I would do, really I'm not sure this can be done, oh and I'm looking for a range for pagination purposes

Comment: the above statement 'so far...' worked with the LIMIT statement after all, thanks for all of the help